# How to set constraints when all buttons are of different size

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I have one view on view controller on that view I have six buttons I want to set constraints to these buttons but I am not able to do that. When I set constraints two of them get compressed don't know why.
I am sharing screen Shot,Please help me Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need six buttons for designing above screen. You can do this by using `UITableView` and custom `UITableViewCell`.

For more : [Customize tableview cell](https://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

Or by using three `UIView`s by sub viewing `UIImage` and `UILable` and then add `UITapGestureRecogniser` to that `UIView`.

For more : [Tap gesture](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/)

Comment: sorry but I want to use buttons only